# How to remove google account from the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to remove my google account which I created on the emulator for Google APIs level 8 AVD.

I tried removing it from `Settings -> Accounts & sync -> Selecting account -> Remove Account`, but I get this message,

> This account is required by some applications. You can only remove it by resetting the phone to factory defaults. You do that in the Settings application, under Privacy

I tried doing it by resetting the phone to factory defaults by going to `Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset -> Reset data -> Erase everything`, and it shows a dialog of `Power Off` message, with indefinite progress bar and later the emulator gets stuck. Then, later, when I close and restart the emulator, the account doesn't get deleted.

Also, I would like to know if it is possible to delete the account through code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Android AVD Manager, launch your avd, and then check `Wipe user data`.

This will restore the AVD to it's initial configuration and wipe all the user data, accounts, and apps.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Settings -> Accounts.
- Click where the `google` is written. You should see the list off accounts.
- Click the account you want to delete. The detail window will open.
- Click on the right corner from menu bar.
- Click on the remove account and popUp will be shown for confirmation.
- Confirm to remove the account. the account will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the Google software form your sdk, and reinstall it.